# PHP Date Time Current Time Add Minutes

Tags: php

Simple question but this is killing my time.

Any simple solution to add 30 minutes to current time in php with GMT+8?

Answer (score 141, accepted):

I think one of the best solutions and easiest is:

```
date("Y-m-d", strtotime("+30 minutes"))
```

Maybe it's not the most efficient but is one of the more understandable.

Comment: If you want to use strtotime relatively to an existing datetime you can do
`code`
strtotime('2011-11-01 + 2 days');

Answer (score 62):

This is an old question that seems answered, but as someone pointed out above, if you use the DateTime class and PHP < 5.3.0, you can't use the add method, but you can use *modify*:

```
$date = new DateTime();
$date->modify("+30 minutes"); //or whatever value you want
```

Comment: You could also use it without `modify()` function like `$date = new DateTime('+30 minutes');`

Answer (score 13):

Time 30 minutes later

```
$newTime = date("Y-m-d H:i:s",strtotime(date("Y-m-d H:i:s")." +30 minutes"))
```

Answer (score 11):

```
$timeIn30Minutes = mktime(idate("H"), idate("i") + 30);
```

or

```
$timeIn30Minutes = time() + 30*60; // 30 minutes * 60 seconds/minute
```

The result will be a UNIX timestamp of the current time plus 30 minutes.

Answer (score 5):

```
echo $date = date('H:i:s', strtotime('13:00:00 + 30 minutes') );
```

13:00:00 - any inputted time

30 minutes - any interval you wish (20 hours, 10 minutes, 1 seconds etc...)

Answer (score 3):

It looks like you are after the DateTime function add - use it like this:

```
$date = new DateTime();
date_add($date, new DateInterval("PT30M"));
```

(Note: untested, but according to the docs, it should work)

Comment: That's a PHP >= 5.3.0 solution as the function ad the class DateInterval is not available in earlier versions.

Comment: Yes, but the title does specify Date Time, so I assume he is using the DateTime class

Comment: DateTime is part of PHP >= 5.2.0 but DateInterval as well as some DateTime methods are not available prior to 5.3.0.

Comment: @a_m0d @tokam Doc says it must start with a "P" for "Period", so, this is the correct way to add 30 minutes: `new DateInterval('PT30M')` (Tested! :))

Answer (score 3):

```
$dateTime = new DateTime('now', new DateTimeZone('Asia/Kolkata')); 
echo $dateTime->modify("+10 minutes")->format("H:i:s A");
```

Comment: While this code may solve the question, [including an explanation](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/114762) of how and why this solves the problem (and ideally how it improves upon other answers) would really help to improve the quality of your post, and probably result in more up-votes. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, not just the person asking now. Please [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/60891983/edit) your answer to add explanations and give an indication of what limitations and assumptions apply.

Answer (score 2):

```
$ck=2016-09-13 14:12:33;
$endtime = date('H-i-s', strtotime("+05 minutes", strtotime($ck)));
```

Answer (score 1):

In addition to Khriz's answer.

If you need to **add 5 minutes** to the **current time** in `Mysql` format you can do:

```
$cur_time=date("Y-m-d H:i:s");
$duration='+5 minutes';
echo date('Y-m-d H:i:s', strtotime($duration, strtotime($cur_time)));
```

Answer (score 0):

time after 30 min, this easiest solution in php

```
date('Y-m-d H:i:s', strtotime("+30 minutes"));
```

for  DateTime class (PHP 5 >= 5.2.0, PHP 7)

```
$dateobj = new DateTime();
$dateobj ->modify("+30 minutes");
```

Answer (score 0):

The question is a little old, but I come back to it often ;p

Another way, which is also a one liner:

```
<?= date_create('2111-11-11 00:00:00')->modify("+30 minutes")->format('Y-m-d h:i:s') ?>
```

Or from timestamp, returns Y-m-d h:i:s:

```
<?= date_create('@'.time())->modify("+30 minutes")->format('Y-m-d h:i:s') ?>
```

Or from timestamp, returns timestamp:

```
<?= date_create('@'.time())->modify("+30 minutes")->format('U') ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
new DateTime('+30minutes')
```

As simple as the accepted solution but gives you a DateTime object instead of a Unix timestamp.

Answer (score -1):

```
$time = strtotime(date('2016-02-03 12:00:00'));
        echo date("H:i:s",strtotime("-30 minutes", $time));
```

Comment: The question was *"Any simple solution to **add** 30 minutes to **current time**"*.