# Add 30 minutes in specified time

Tags: php, time

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [PHP Date Time Current Time Add Minutes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/985818/php-date-time-current-time-add-minutes)

I need to add 30 minutes in specified time, The below is result but how it will

4:50 pm
30 minutes
result= 5:20 pm

4:50 pm is not current time
30 minutes need to add in specified time
and the result is 5:20 pm

Comment: Please note that the question seems to refer to a string with `"4:40 pm"`, not a date.

Answer (score 2):

use strtotime

```
echo date('G:i:s', strtotime('NOW + 30 minutes'));
```

[demo](http://sandbox.phpcode.eu/g/a2bc5.php) (GTM + 1)

Comment: not need to add in current time i need to add minutes in specified time like "4:50 pm"

Answer (score 1):

```
echo date('g:i a', time()+30*60);
```

this is for you.

Answer (score -1):

[Here's an article that shows some date math examples](http://php.about.com/od/advancedphp/qt/math_time_php.htm).  You might also find the [PHP Time Manual](http://php.net/manual/en/function.time.php) useful.

Comment: This article assumes that daylight saving time does not exist.