# adding two times(time() + seconds)

Tags: php, datetime, time

I want to add X seconds to the current time

So it should be like this

 `current_time()+$x`

 and formatted as `dd-mm-YYYY hh:mm:ss`

is there any way to do this?

Comment: add to what? this question makes little sesne

Comment: please don't give `negative points`
if you don't like please leave it, as if it marked negative more times, my account will be blocked. So Please

Comment: I can vote as i please.

Comment: adding `number of seconds` to current `time`.
like add `180 seconds` to current time and make it look like `2:52 AM`

Comment: Check this question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/985818/php-date-time-current-time-add-minutes

Comment: Also check this tutorial on php.net about `date->add` http://php.net/manual/en/datetime.add.php

Comment: yeah I'd checked that too.. thanks a lot to all of you for your help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Better (and shorter) then mine, method (suggested by [@Dan](https://stackoverflow.com/users/796393/dan)):**

```
$currentDate = date('d-m-Y H:i:s', (time()));
$shiftedDate = date('d-m-Y H:i:s', (time()+5922725));
```

**My answer:**

You need `mktime()` function and `date()` function. You have to synergize this functions to achieve what you want.

Examples:

```
$currentTime = mktime(date("H"), date("i"), date("s"), date("m")  , date("d")+1, date("Y"));
$shiftedTime = mktime(date("H"), date("i"), date("s"),+5922725, date("m")  , date("d")+1, date("Y")); // with shift
```

Note, that `mktime()` function returns Unix Timestamp as result, so u have to convert timestamp to real date:

```
$currentTime = date('d-m-Y H:i:s', mktime(date("H"), date("i"), date("s"), date("m")  , date("d")+1, date("Y")));
// same for shifted
```

Sources:

[mktime() on php.net](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.mktime.php)
[date() on php.net](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.date.php)

Comment: Why not just use time()? Like this: `date('d-m-Y H:i:s', (time()+5922725));`

Comment: Because I didn't know about it :) Know I do, I edited my answer.

Comment: ahh... That's pretty cool :)
but first method didn't worked for me and gives an error that some method has been deprecated.
but the method provided by @Dan is perfectly working
Thanks man.

Comment: Deprecated method or not depends on what version of php you use.

Answer (score 2):

i'd go with [strtotime](http://www.php.net/manual/de/function.strtotime.php) as it's easy to follow.

```
$timestamp = strtotime('+5 sec');
// date('d-m-Y H:i:s', $timestamp);
```